# Select column from Hive if exists

Tags: hive, hiveql

Is there a way to conditionally select each column only if the column exist in Hive?

Here is my pseudo-hql:

```
SELECT attr1 IF EXISTS, attr2 IF EXISTS, attr3 IF EXISTS
FROM some_table;
```

If attr1 & attr3 exist in the table, but attr2 does not exist, this should return to me all the rows from attr1 & attr3 without complaining about the absence of attr2. This syntax does NOT work, and Hive is very restrictive about inner queries too so I don't want to go that route unless necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to do it with a single query. 
But you can do either of them below and develop a logic to leverage the results gained from them:

1)Hive metastore client(HiveMetastoreClient.getFields) to get the fields.

2)Desc the table and get the description.

After getting the results(from any one of the above) iterate through the result to check if the fields in your query are present in the result. If it is then execute entire query. Or skip those which are not present.